# Why is the set of formal propositions enumerable?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, discrete-mathematics

This question derives from my Discrete Math Homework:

A set S is recursively enumerable if one can write a program such that, once the program is launched, it will print a list of elements of S and, for all elements s ∈ S , the program will eventually print out the element s .

Which of the following are recursively enumerable sets?

A. N (where N means nature numbers)

B. N×N (where N means nature numbers)

C. The power set P(N) of subsets of N.

D. The set of formal propositions.

E. The set of rational numbers Q .

The answer is "A,B,D,E"

I'm confused about the choice "D. The set of formal propositions"

Thanks indeed!

PS: "formal propositions" means "the proposition made up of specific symbol rather than English words" (for instance, ョx∈N, x<5)

Comment: This is just a math homework, not a SO question

Comment: sorry for that, I print out all the question is just in order to make it more clear and I'll be careful about this for next time I ask question on SO

Comment: You should ask such things at math.stackexchange

Comment: It depends critically on how you define "formal propositions." The "PS" is not a definition.

Answer (score 0):

Formal propositions are recursively enumerable only if we assume that we are only interested in the "writable" ones (such, which have **finite length** in terms of symbols from some **finite/enumerable vocablurary**).

In such case we can write the program, which given pair (A,B) writes A'th proposition of length B, and than use our program for writing down NxN to write them down. The existance of the first program is based on assumption that: we use some finite set of symbols to write them down (or at least enumerable); our propositions are finite in terms of length (our program has to be able to print them out).

Comment: "Writable" ones being the only ones contemplated by the definition.

Comment: thanks, a little crystal now. But considering this, can I use the same technique to print out the "C. The power set P(N) of subsets of N." in other words, treat the "subset" as string, {1} has length 1, {12} has length 2, {123} has length 3

Comment: @Charlie - It was just in case one would try to count some propositions on real numbers here. Is this the reason for -1?

soul376 - yes, you could go the same way, simply iterating through subsets ordered in this kind of order

Comment: @lejlot: Why would only propositions of finite length be enumerable?

Comment: @Bergi Well, according to authors definition "he program will eventually print out the element s .", and only finite sequences can be printed out, right (remark that I've written finite, not of bounded length)? And if you mean my usage of "finite/enumerable" I meant "finite OR enumerable"

Comment: Good God, what are they teaching kids in computer science these days?

Comment: @soul376, of course you can: you just typed it, right?We're not talking about the set *described* by the string, but the string containing the description.

Answer (score -1):

Because you can write a program that will print out all the formal propositions expressed in symbolism.  Consider the recursive definition of the set of formal propositions:

1. The alphabet of primitive symbols; each is a formal proposition
2. combinations of formal propositions using the various operators asre formal propositions
3. nothing else is a formal proposition

So you start with, say, {a, b, c}, then {(a+b),(a/b)...}, then {((a+b)+c) ... } and so on.

Now, that program never terminates -- you can always make a new f.p. by adding another term -- but you get all the f.p. in some order, so you can print them

1. FP1
2. FP2

and so forth.  So, you can enumerate them: recursively enumerable.

Comment: Definition used lacks the assumption of enumerability of "various operators". If you consider non enumerable set of operators you get something which is not enumerable.

Comment: Okay, how do you propose to have a non-denumerable set of operators in a formal string system?

Comment: n fact, a formal proposition a/k/a a string in a formal language **by definition** uses a finite set of operators and is therefore trivially enumerable.